# How can I calculate cost for transfering files from S3 Standard-IA to S3 One Zone-IA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cost-management

I need to calculate cost to do transmittion/transmit/move whole data from S3 Standard-IA to S3 One Zone-IA (for cost saving).

I need to calculate all cost that apply to transfer because I have to transfer millions files and total 20TB size of data. Can someone explain me on below example.

ex:
Bucket A: Has 1 million files (3TB total size).
Bucket B: Has 300 files (3TB total size).
region: ap-south-1

I couldn't find cost detail for S3 Standard-IA to S3 One Zone-IA (all over std to ia or Glacier details present not this)

Comment: Did you try the S3 pricing calculator?

Comment: that also will be fine but don't which cost are included for calculating this,

Comment: @jarmod Basically I need to know except Lifecycle Transition requests((0.01$ per 1k)) what other charges will apply?